# Is there a Collection in .NET 3.5 that allows one thread to add data while another removes data without locking the whole thing?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I want to emphasize the "3.5" in the question. I am aware that a lot of this stuff has changed in 4.0, but I do not yet have access to this.

I have a TCP client class that takes data from another application and puts it in a Queue, and the UI thread periodically calls a function to get data from it. Currently, I do a lock on the Queue while accessing it from both sides, and I'm getting problems when too much data comes in over the network.

I figure I could implement some sort of circular buffer to get this to work, but I'm assuming this can already be done using some .NET class.

Comment: @Oded System.Collections.Concurrent is only in framework 4 and later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Queue` with a lock seems like a reasonable approach, and I wouldn't expect performance problems as long as you are only holding the lock for the call to the `Queue` method (writer side) or `Dequeue` method (reader side).  Are you sure the lock is the issue?

Note that a `ReaderWriterLock` as suggested in @Jon B's answer doesn't really help since you only have one reader, and in any case you would need a write lock to call `Dequeue`.

The only case where a `ReaderWriterLock` might help would be if you had multiple reader threads calling the `Peek` method - for which they would only need a read lock.

Comment: The Queue and lock were not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

If the queue is the bottleneck, try the following approach. Have a load balancer and a queue for each consumer. The load balancer places incoming requests into a consumer's queue; this is done based on which consumer queue is most free (say smallest queue size).

I'm making lots of assumptions about speed and number of producers and consumers here, but this is a basic idea. Your new bottleneck would be the load balancer. As you can see, this works when there are computation intensive tasks to be done by consumers .

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a try to [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). That link also contains sample of how it can be used. And it is more preferable than [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The .NET Framework has two reader-writer locks, ReaderWriterLockSlim
>   and ReaderWriterLock. ReaderWriterLockSlim is recommended for all new
>   development. ReaderWriterLockSlim is similar to ReaderWriterLock, but
>   it has simplified rules for recursion and for upgrading and
>   downgrading lock state. ReaderWriterLockSlim avoids many cases of
>   potential deadlock. In addition, the performance of
>   ReaderWriterLockSlim is significantly better than ReaderWriterLock.

However as @Joe correctly pointed out you'll need to put writer lock for both pop and push operations.